# bind ltc2947-spi driver on BeagleBone Black

Tags: drivers, bind, sysfs, beagleboneblack

Having trouble binding a SPI driver on the BeagleBone Black. The driver in question, `ltc2947-spi`, is in the linux mainline, but not in the beaglebone kernel tree. When I get this working, I'll submit a PR to add it.

I compiled the ltc2947 drivers as an out-of-tree module using [this repo](https://gitlab.com/bluesquall/kmod-ltc2947) (also on [github](https://github.com/bluesquall/kmod-ltc2947)).

```
 % sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 % find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -iname "*ltc29*"
 % make
```

The module compiles fine, and `modinfo` produces the expected output:

```
 % sudo modinfo ltc2947-spi.ko                                  
filename:       /home/lily/kmod-ltc2947/ltc2947-spi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    LTC2947 SPI power and energy monitor driver
author:         Nuno Sa <nuno.sa@analog.com>
alias:          spi:ltc2947
depends:        ltc2947-core
name:           ltc2947_spi
vermagic:       5.4.70-ti-r19 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8
```

And `insmod` appears to insert the module correctly (note there are two modules, since the SPI and I2C drivers for this chip share a common core):

```
 % sudo insmod ./ltc2947-core.ko && sudo insmod ./ltc2947-spi.ko
 % grep ltc2947 /proc/modules
ltc2947_spi 16384 0 - Live 0x00000000 (O)
ltc2947_core 24576 1 ltc2947_spi, Live 0x00000000 (O)
 % tree /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947 
/sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947
├── bind
├── module -> ../../../../module/ltc2947_spi
├── uevent
└── unbind

1 directory, 3 files
```

From here, I need to bind the driver to a device on the SPI bus. I'm using the Mikroe VCP Monitor 3 Click connected to SPI via the mikroBus Cape. The board is in slot 1 right now, so the pin connections are:

- P9_28: CS
- P9_29: MISO
- P9_30: MOSI
- P9_31: SCK

It is not yet clear to me where I specify the chip select pin, or how to determine the string to echo to `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ltc2947/bind`.

The pins from the cape correspond to `spi1`, according to this diagram:
[image: beaglebone black SPI pinout]
and I noticed `spi1` was already bound to `spidev`, so I unbind it:

```
 % echo "spi1.0" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/spi/drivers/spidev/unbind
spi1.0
 % echo "spi1.1" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/spi/drivers/spidev/unbind
spi1.1
 % tree /sys/bus/spi/drivers/spidev                              
/sys/bus/spi/drivers/spidev
├── bind
├── module -> ../../../../module/spidev
├── spi0.0 -> ../../../../devices/platform/ocp/48000000.interconnect/48000000.interconnect:segment@0/48030000.target-module/48030000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0
├── spi0.1 -> ../../../../devices/platform/ocp/48000000.interconnect/48000000.interconnect:segment@0/48030000.target-module/48030000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.1
├── uevent
└── unbind

3 directories, 3 files
```

But then when I try to bind it to the `ltc2947` driver, it gives the error `"/sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind: No such device"`:

```
 % echo "spi1" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind 
spi1
tee: /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind: No such device
 % echo "spi1.0" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind
spi1.0
tee: /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind: No such device
 % echo "spi1.1" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind
spi1.1
tee: /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ltc2947/bind: No such device
```

Echoing to the `bind` under `/sys/module` produces the same result:

```
 % echo "spi1" | sudo tee -a /sys/module/ltc2947_spi/drivers/spi:ltc2947/bind  
spi1
tee: '/sys/module/ltc2947_spi/drivers/spi:ltc2947/bind': No such device
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [a page on the Analog Devices Wiki](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/hwmon/ltc2947#example_i2c_spi_device_initialization) that pointed me in the right direction.

> Currently, the devices can only be instantiated via device tree.

So for the Beaglebone Black, I drafted a device tree overlay and sent [a pull request](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/pull/210) to bb.org-overlays.

I've tested this with a LED + resistor as the load on the VCP Monitor 3 click, and can successfully read voltage, current, power, and energy from files under `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0`, e.g.:

```
lily@beaglebone /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0
% cat name                 
ltc2947
lily@beaglebone /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0
% echo 1 > in0_reset_history 
lily@beaglebone /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0
% cat in0_label            
VP-VM
lily@beaglebone /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0
% cat in0_input
0

# Here I turned on 5V @ 12 mA to light an LED

lily@beaglebone /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0
% cat in0_input  
5054
```